# Python 2 memory error

Tags: python, audio

I am using Python PsychoPy 1.81.00 and am receiving a Memory error that causes the experiment to prematurely terminate. I ran the same procedure with 2 visual stimuli and did not receive this error, but when I switched one of them to an auditory stimulus I did.

Here is the exact message I receive regarding this matter:

```
C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\shape.py:281: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if self.fillRGB!=None:
C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\shape.py:287: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if self.lineRGB!=None and self.lineWidth!=0.0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diamonda\Desktop\Amy\Group1_ToneVisual\UGH_lastrun.py", line 3195, in <module>
    short_stim2 = sound.Sound('B', secs=short_dur)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.setSound(value=value, secs=secs, octave=octave)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 135, in setSound
    self._setSndFromNote(value.capitalize(), secs, octave, hamming=hamming)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 167, in _setSndFromNote
    self._setSndFromFreq(thisFreq, secs, hamming=hamming)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 177, in _setSndFromFreq
    self._setSndFromArray(outArr)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.00-py2.7.egg\psychopy\sound.py", line 291, in _setSndFromArray
    thisArray= (thisArray*2**15).astype(numpy.int16)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Please provide code... `x == None` vs `x is None`?

Comment: What's the value of `short_dur`? If the sound to be created is too long, its waveform data won't fit in memory, seems like that's what's happening here.

Comment: Just doing a quick test on my PC, I can create a sound that's 100 seconds long, but trying to make one 1000 seconds long gives me a `MemoryError`